# How to use CONCAT to join five columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

HOW DO I USE CONCAT IN BIGQUERY TO JOIN FIVE COLUMN

I WAS TRYING TO JOIN FIVE COLUMNS IN A TABLE. LIKE THIS

SELECT CONCAT(start_station_id, start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype, num_trips)

I want a result with space between them.

Comment: You can use `ARRAY_TO_STRING([start_station_id, start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype, num_trips], ' ')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(start_station_id, ' ', start_station_name, ' ', end_station_name, ' ', usertype, ' ', num_trips) AS concatenated_columns
FROM your_table;
```

The query above will concatenate the five columns `start_station_id`, `start_station_name`, `end_station_name`, `usertype`, and `num_trips` with a space between each column. The result will be a new column called `concatenated_columns`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CONCAT_WS to specify space as delimeter:

SELECT
CONCAT_WS(' ', start_station_id, start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype, num_trips) AS joined_columns
FROM
your_table_name;